# Constraints not re-sizing stack view

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, autolayout

I am trying to drag a verticle stack view onto a view and set it's constraints to fill the entire view. The way I went about it is I selected the view on the main.storyboard document outline and then dragged the verticle stack view from the object library on the right.  Then I control-dragged from the stack view in the document outline to the view and set the 4 constraints (leading-margin, trailing-margin, verticle and horizontal spacing) on the pop-up.  I then went into constraints and made all the constants 0.  the stack view should then resize to fill the entire view but it doesn't...  Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A stack view sets its frame size according its content size, you can't just define some edges constraints to your stackview to resize it

If you want the stack view to have the same size of your UIView, add content to it with the same size of your UIView.

Take a look at this :

[image]

I added a view inside the view controller. Then I added a stackview inside this view.

The stackview has 2 constraints : top and leading space to 0.

To have my stackview with the same size as the UIView : I added another UIView (it could be anything else) to my stack view.

On this second UIView I set two constraint : equal height and equal width with the first UIView.

So now the stack view contains a content (2nd UIView), with a width and a height. 
So the stack view have the same size with the initial view.

Comment: i'm busy with the Udacity introduction to ios and swift course and on that video the view resizes to fill the UIView when the constraints constants is set to 0.  e.g. distence to top layout guide = 0 and distence to bottom layout guide = 0???  ii'm supposed to add to horizontal stack views with buttons onto the verticle stack view however the verticle stack view is too small...

Comment: Take a look at my edit and tell me if you still have problems.

Comment: If you could link an image of the final result this could help

Comment: How do I update the frame to show the results of the constraints?  So why add another view to the stack view?  Why isn't it possible to set the stack view to fill it's super view?  Thanks for all your effort

Comment: update frame : `Cmd + alt + =`
A stack view is only a container which help you to manage the position of your UIView (vertically, horizontally). You can set it a position if you want but the size of the UIStackView is determined by its content

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4WIT5saiAg this is what i'm doing but it's not working out as it does in that video...  In that video he set constraints on the stack view before adding content and it resized???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110607/discussion-between-user2094257-and-anthony-roani).

Answer (score 1):

1. give it leading , trailing , top and bottom spacing from
   superview.
2. make all constraints to 0.
3. Update frame

[image]

Comment: I did exactly that...  Have a look at this  youtube.com/watch?v=m4WIT5saiAg  This is what I did however the verticle stack view doesn't resize to fit it's parent view